# C++ static member initialization in python extension module

Tags: python, c++, swig, python-extensions

## Short version

I don't understand how to reliably initialize static members for a python extension.  In particular, how can I ensure a particular load order for code from different compilation units, so that certain dependencies are satisfied?

## Long version

I have some code that computes various combinatoric functions many times, like the factorial, binomial, etc.  It's much more efficient to just construct a table for these things once, and then do the lookup on them.  And I need a nice interface for getting the values, so I just make c++ classes, with the tables as static members.

As the simplest example, to compute factorials, I have the following.  In `Combinatorics.hpp`:

```
  class FactorialFunctor {
  private:
    static const std::vector<double> FactorialTable;
  public:
    FactorialFunctor() { };
    inline double operator()(const unsigned int i) const {
      return FactorialTable[i];
    }
  };
```

In `Combinatorics.cpp`:

```
const std::vector<double> FactorialFunctor::FactorialTable = FactorialTableCalculator();
```

where `FactorialTableCalculator` is a local function that just returns the appropriate vector.  [Those `operator()`s get more complicated for binomials, etc., which is why I use classes to wrap these things.]

I use SWIG to wrap the `c++` code up, and use it from python.  This was all going well until I compiled my code on a new cluster that I'm using.  Now I think I was just getting lucky previously.

As soon as I imported my python module on the new cluster, python would segfault.  Python didn't even get back from the import step.  Using `gdb`, I tracked this down to another part of the code, whose initialization calls a `Factorial` functor.  But the `FactorialTable` hadn't been initialized yet, so the whole thing croaked.

So I need to ensure that my factorial is calculated before that other code is calculated.  I tell distutils about it in the desired order, but obviously this isn't the order they get called on this cluster.  Is there some stage in the linking process that I need to be careful with or something?

If you're really motivated, you can browse the code [here](https://github.com/MOBle/SphericalFunctions/blob/8fe4f0a3db91a16f5b36edefafb554038e3cb94a/Combinatorics.hpp) and [here](https://github.com/MOBle/SphericalFunctions/blob/8fe4f0a3db91a16f5b36edefafb554038e3cb94a/Combinatorics.cpp), and the line that gives the segfault [here](https://github.com/MOBle/SphericalFunctions/blob/8fe4f0a3db91a16f5b36edefafb554038e3cb94a/WignerDMatrices.cpp#L35).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable way to force the order your static members are initialized.

Looking at the code however I think that the thing you need is not a *static* member rather than a singleton. Singletons in C++ are usually implemented using functions like so:

```
FactorialFunctorData& _FactorialFunctorData()
{
    static FactorialFunctorData data_;
    return data_;
}
```

This way you may force the order on the execution time (by calling functions in the order needed).